# If element is empty or not have any element add class to its parent container else remove class

Tags: jquery

How can I use an `if`/`else` statement with `has()` & not `has()` in jQuery?

In my code on clicking `.fig-caption` I want to add an `active` class to the parent element having `class="figcaption"`. If the `.fig-figcaption` does not have any element add an `active` class else remove the `active` class.

```js
$(".figcaption figure > .fig-figcaption").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).not(figcaption, span)) {
    $(this).parents(".figcaption").addClass("active");
  } else {
    $(this).parents(".figcaption").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="figcaption">
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption"></div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
      <figcaption>Sed porttitor lectus nibh.</figcaption>
      <span class="photo-date">March 23, 2018</span>
      <span class="photo-title">Spinning Out of Control 1</span>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
      <span class="photo-date">March 23, 2018</span>
      <span class="photo-title">Spinning Out of Control 1</span>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
      <figcaption>Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.</figcaption>
      <span class="photo-date">March 23, 2018</span>
      <span class="photo-title">Spinning Out of Control 1</span>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
    </div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
      <figcaption>Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Vivamus magna justo</figcaption>
      <span class="photo-date">March 23, 2018</span>
      <span class="photo-title">Spinning Out of Control 1</span>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: First, be careful about strings, in `.not(figcaption, `, "figcaption" is considered as a variable because of missing quotes. Also, `not` is not what you think it is: it removes elements from the selection, I think you are looking for [.is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/) or [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of find and length

```js
$(".figcaption figure > .fig-figcaption").on('click', function(){
//console.log($(this).find('figcaption, span'))
    if($(this).find('figcaption, span').length == 0) {
      $(this).parents(".figcaption").addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(this).parents(".figcaption").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
```

```css
.active {
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="figcaption">
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption"></div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
      <figcaption>Sed porttitor lectus nibh.</figcaption>
      <span class="photo-date">March 23, 2018</span>
      <span class="photo-title">Spinning Out of Control 1</span>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
      <span class="photo-date">March 23, 2018</span>
      <span class="photo-title">Spinning Out of Control 1</span>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
      <figcaption>Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.</figcaption>
      <span class="photo-date">March 23, 2018</span>
      <span class="photo-title">Spinning Out of Control 1</span>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">empty
    </div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
      <figcaption>Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Vivamus magna justo</figcaption>
      <span class="photo-date">March 23, 2018</span>
      <span class="photo-title">Spinning Out of Control 1</span>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).find(figcaption, span)` will cause an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `children()` function get all children. If the length of that result is 0 you don't have any element child nodes.

Also changed `parents()` to `closest()` since it is slightly more efficient.

```js
$(".figcaption figure > .fig-figcaption").on('click', function(){
    if($(this).children().length === 0) {
      $(this).closest(".figcaption").addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(this).closest(".figcaption").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: blue;
}

.fig-figcaption {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="figcaption" >
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption"></div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
      <figcaption>Sed porttitor lectus nibh.</figcaption>
      <span class="photo-date">March 23, 2018</span>
      <span class="photo-title">Spinning Out of Control 1</span>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
      <span class="photo-date">March 23, 2018</span>
      <span class="photo-title">Spinning Out of Control 1</span>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
      <figcaption>Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.</figcaption>
      <span class="photo-date">March 23, 2018</span>
      <span class="photo-title">Spinning Out of Control 1</span>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
    </div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="fig-figcaption">
      <figcaption>Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Vivamus magna justo</figcaption>
      <span class="photo-date">March 23, 2018</span>
      <span class="photo-title">Spinning Out of Control 1</span>
    </div>  
 </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: what's a **het element nodes**?

Comment: you mean the nodes of type element no "element nodes"

Comment: Is there a difference?

Comment: element nodes to me looks like a parent / child relationship

Comment: Apparently children only returns element nodes these days. Removed that function.